# High Sierra WebView blocks anchor tag navigation

Tags: macos, webview

I have a Mac app that displays info in a WebView. Quite an old app now and in Objective-C which I am rapidly forgetting.

The WebView contains anchor tags to allow navigation within the pages, both by clicking on links in the page displayed, or by clicking tabs in the UI which send Javascript to the WebView.  In High Sierra this no longer works although it displays no error.

It appears that I need to implement `isKeyExcludedFromWebScript:` but my attempts to do so have failed.

Do I need to sub-class WebView? Putting `isKeyExcludedFromWebScript:` and `isSelectorExcludedFromWebScript:` in the View Controller containing the WebView doesn't work - they never get called.

If anyone has any advice or examples, I would be most grateful.
I am afraid that the answer will be to upgrade the app to use WKWebView but I was hoping for a quick work-around until I get time to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question here as I have worked out a solution.

The problem was that I was loading an HTML string into the WebView and when I tried to use internal navigation links, it didn't have a base URL to use as a prefix and so the anchor navigation never worked.

It used to work, prior to High Sierra, so there must be something new about how WebViews operate.

The solution was to save the HTML string to a temporary file and have the WebView load that file's URL instead of loading the string directly.

This applies to both WebView and WKWebView.